# How to include Realm ID in the jwt token - keycloak

Tags: jwt, microservices, keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper

I'm using keycloak as my user management and trying to generated jwt to be used in other microservices, and as i understand to add new filed or info to the jwt, i need to create new client scope then link it to predefine mapper to be included in the jwt but i can't find any predefined `realm id` mapper, so is their any other way to add the realm id to the jwt ? or I'm messing something from the predefined mapper?

I'm using keycloak `version 19.0.1`

Comment: Can't you try to infer from the 'iss' claim in the token?

Comment: What does this have to do with Realm, part of MongoDB Realm - the database?

Comment: @Jay nothing I have removed that tag

Comment: @dreamcrash did you find a answer for this ?

Comment: @csf I can added as an answer to this question if you are interested